# Configure Microsoft Portal Authentication SAML2

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, microsoft-portal

I'm trying to configure the Microsoft Portal add-on for Dynamics 365 to work with an external identity provider that supports SAML2.

I've followed all the steps as described in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/configure-saml2-settings

The portal is correctly redirecting me to the identity provider login screen, I enter my credentials and then I am redirected to the URL specified in the `AssertionConsumerServiceUrl` site setting, which should be: `https://mycustomportal.microsoftcrmportals.com/signin-saml2`

At this point, we get a 404 and we do not get logged in.

I tried setting up the SAML2 Azure AD settings which take us to a different endpoint (`https://mycustomportal.microsoftcrmportals.com/signin-azure-ad`) and it works as expected.

Has anyone had any luck in getting the generic SAML2 sign in working?